# Generating combinations from two lists with specific order in Python 3

Tags: python, list, combinations

Someone have any idea on how can I take two equal size lists, for example:

```
list_1 = [i, j ,k]
list_2 = [x, y, z]
```

and generate all the possible combinations from the merging of them, while (this is the tricky part) - I would like to get the combinations in specific order, like in the source lists, like this:

```
 ijk, iyk, iyz, ijz, xyz, xyk, xjz, xjk
```

Note that each item in the source lists keeps his location in the new list. For example, 'x' and 'i' should be first in the new list, and so couldn't be together never.

Thank for the help!

Comment: isn't this equivalent to get `sorted(all_three_element_picks(list_1+list_2))`?

Comment: It's unclear to which criteria to sort!

Comment: The criteria is that any item in the source lists  keeps his location in the new list, this is mean for example that 'x' and 'i' should be first in the new list, and so couldn't be together never.

Comment: Edit your question to include that info, rather than just commenting! And that's not a sorting criterion, but a creation method, at best!

Comment: OK. Thanks! (Sorry, I'm new here)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably consider this problem as a problem of chosing three-sequences of choices between "pick from list 1" (`0`) and "pick from list 2" (`1`).

Thus, if you consider your sequence `ijk`, you could represent it as `000`, and `xyk` would be `110`.

Then, the problem gets really easy: it's just the sequence of numbers that can be represented with three binary digits, i.e.

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

also know as all numbers between (including) 0 and 7.